# Joomla session and registry dependency?

Tags: php, session, joomla, joomla2.5

following is my session data that i got from joomla session table.
Now my question is i am totally lost between Jregistry and Jsession.

what i found by reading code from joomla platform

```
Jregistry is not using session variable at all in set() and get().
```

My question now is, data stored in Jregistry is passed in session why?? and can anyone may please route me to the piece of code resposible for passing registry to session.

and a function found in Japplication setUserState is using some session variable registry what is it?

```
public function setUserState($key, $value)
{
    $session = JFactory::getSession();
    $registry = $session->get('registry');

    if (!is_null($registry))
    {
        return $registry->set($key, $value);
    }

    return null;
}
```

Session data i found for guest user i is integer and s is string

> __default|a:8: {s:15:"session.counter";i:1;s:19:"session.timer.start";i:1384090452;s:18:"session.timer.last";i:1384090452;s:17:"session.timer.now";i:1384090452;s:22:"session.client.browser";s:107:"Mozilla/5.0
>   (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/535.11 (KHTML, like Gecko)
>   Chrome/17.0.963.33
>   Safari/535.11";***s:8:"registry";O:9:"JRegistry":1:{s:7:"\0\0\0data";O:8:"stdClass":0:{}}***s:4:"user";O:5:"JUser":24:{s:9:"\0\0\0isRoot";N;s:2:"id";i:0;s:4:"name";N;s:8:"username";N;s:5:"email";N;s:8:"password";N;s:14:"password_clear";s:0:"";s:5:"block";N;s:9:"sendEmail";i:0;s:12:"registerDate";N;s:13:"lastvisitDate";N;s:10:"activation";N;s:6:"params";N;s:6:"groups";a:1:{i:0;s:2:"13";}s:5:"guest";i:1;s:13:"lastResetTime";N;s:10:"resetCount";N;s:10:"\0\0\0_params";O:9:"JRegistry":1:{s:7:"\0\0\0data";O:8:"stdClass":0:{}}s:14:"\0\0\0_authGroups";N;s:14:"\0\0\0_authLevels";a:3:{i:0;i:1;i:1;i:1;i:2;i:5;}s:15:"\0\0\0_authActions";N;s:12:"\0\0\0_errorMsg";N;s:10:"\0\0\0_errors";a:0:{}s:3:"aid";i:0;}s:13:"session.token";s:32:"845b6df35056177aeb84ac26db333607";}

Answer (score 0):

The data passed in JRegistry is not stored in session.

JRegistry is a class wrapping a multidimensionnal array and allow to access the values using a '.', but JRegistry itself has nothing to do with JSession.

They use JRegistry as container for an array of data.

The code reponsible to set the registry is : https://github.com/joomla/joomla-cms/blob/1d817d9762b0e4264d99f2257ce23dd68628df00/libraries/legacy/application/application.php#L1120 .

Comment: why i am confused is that string in session data     <<<<s:8:"registry";O:9:"JRegistry":1:{s:7:"\0\0\0data";O:8:"stdClass":0:{}}>>>     is showing Jregistry object.

Comment: and in setUserState() method it is taking registry from session variable and updating it